# Can I shorten this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the need to check whether strings adhere to a particular ID format.

The format of the ID is as follows:

`aBcDe-fghIj-KLmno-pQRsT-uVWxy`

A sequence of five blocks of five letters upper case or lower case, separated by one dash.

I have the following regular expression that works:

```
string idFormat = "[a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{5}";
```

Note that there is no trailing dash, but the all of the blocks within the ID follow the same format. Therefore, I would like to be able to represent this sequence of four blocks with a trailing dash inside the regular expression and avoid the duplication.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
string idFormat = "[[a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}]{4}[a-zA-Z]{5}";
```

How do I shorten this regular expression and get rid of the duplicated parts?

What is the best way to ensure that each block does also not contain any numbers?

---

Edit:

Thanks for the replies, I now understand the grouping in regular expressions.

I'm running a few tests against the regular expression, the following are relevant:

Test 1: `aBcDe-fghIj-KLmno-pQRsT-uVWxy`
Test 2: `abcde-fghij-klmno-pqrst-uvwxy`

With the following regular expression, both tests pass:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{5}-){4}[a-zA-Z]{5}$
```

With the next regular expression, test 1 fails:

```
^([a-z]{5}-){4}[a-z]{5}$
```

Several answers have said that it is OK to omit the A-Z when using a-z, but in this case it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can set regex options to be case insensitive, you could replace all `[a-zA-Z]` with just plain `[a-z]`. Furthermore, `[-]{1}` can be written as `-`.

Your grouping should be done with `(`, `)`, not with `[`, `]` (although you're correctly using the latter in specifying character sets.

Depending on context, you probably want to throw in `^...$` which matches start and end of string, respectively, to verify that the *entire* string is a match (i.e. that there are no extra characters).

In javascript, something like this:

```
/^([a-z]{5}-){4}[a-z]{5}$/i
```

Comment: Please check the edited post, I'm having trouble getting the regex working with just the a-z as opposed to a-zA-Z

Comment: @fletcher: you need to *specify* that the regex should be case insensitive. how you do that depends on what language you're doing this in. in javascript, it is with the `i` as in my example, in C# it is `new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` There are also cases where you *cannot* make it case insensitive, such as ASP.NET RegexValidator controls, that don't implement support for RegexOptions, and possibly some programming languages that might not support it at all.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `^(i)([a-z]{5}-){4}[a-z]{5}$` where (i) turns on case insensitivity

Comment: @Gary: That should be `(?i)`, not `(i)`.  Also, it's not supported in JavaScript, which may or may not be relevant, given that OP hasn't specified a flavor.

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

```
([a-z]{5}-){4}[a-z]{5}
```

and make it case insensitive.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of the case insensitive.

Comment: Make sure you do `^ $` at the beginning/end otherwise this would match on `1651651aBcDe-fghIj-KLmno-pQRsT-uVWxy1625361$%4g$%^£$48` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, though you might want to check it:

```
[a-zA-Z]{5}(-[a-zA-Z]{5}){4}
```

*(One group of five letters, followed by [dash+group of five letters] four times)*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string idFormat = "([a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}){4}[a-zA-Z]{5}";
```

I.e. you basically replace your brackets by parentheses. Brackets are not meant for grouping but for defining a class of accepted characters.

However, be aware that with shortened versions, you *can* use the expression for validating the string, *but not* for analyzing it. If you want to process the 5 groups of characters, you will want to put them in 5 groups:

```
string idFormat =
    "([a-zA-Z]{5})-([a-zA-Z]{5})-([a-zA-Z]{5})-([a-zA-Z]{5})-([a-zA-Z]{5})";
```

so you can address each group and process it.

Comment: No way, it was just swapping the square brackets for the parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z]{5}[-]{1}){4}[a-zA-Z]{5}
```